# Associando stack com struct em C++

Tags: c++, stack

Construir o seguinte programa:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

struct Register{

    string name;
    int birth;
    char sex;

    void Insert(string st_name,int st_birth, char st_sex){

        name=st_name;
        birth=st_birth;
        sex=st_sex;
    }

};

stack <Register> stack_register;

int main(void){

    Register data[5];

    data[0].Insert("Pkrtvx",151,'M');
    stack_register.push(data[0]);

    data[1].Insert("IKXS_36080",159,'M');
    stack_register.push(data[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Minhas dúvidas:

1. Será que eu estou inserindo os dados da `struct` na minha `stack` da forma correta?
2. Como faço para mostrar o elemento do topo neste caso? Pois sempre que eu uso o top acabada me retorna um erro.

Veja o código abaixo para entender:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

struct Register{

    string name;
    int birth;
    char sex;

    void Insert(string st_name,int st_birth, char st_sex){

        name=st_name;
        birth=st_birth;
        sex=st_sex;
    }

};

stack <Register> stack_register;

int main(void){

    Register data[5];

    data[0].Insert("IKXS_36080",125,'M');
    stack_register.push(data[0]);

    data[1].Insert("IKXS_36080",105,'M');
    stack_register.push(data[1]);

    cout << stack_register.top(); //O erro estar aqui

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pode [edit] a pergunta e adicionar a mensagem de erro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro que dá é:

> no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout <<
>   stack_register.std::stack<_Tp, _Sequence>::top

Que diz que o operador de escrita `<<` não sabe como escrever uma estrutura `Register` na consola.

Tem duas soluções.

1. Escrever os campos da estrutura manualmente:

   ```
   cout << "Nome: " << stack_register.top().name;
   ```

   Note que tem o `.name` no fim para escrever o nome
2. Construir uma função de escrita personalizada

   Isto faz-se implementando o operador de escrita `<<`, assim:

   ```
   std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &o,const Register &a){
       //Aqui consideramos que escrever um register na consola escreve o nome e o sexo
       return o<<"Nome: "<<a.name<<"\nSexo: "<<a.sex; 
   }
   ```

   O que já permite fazer o que estava inicialmente

   ```
   cout<<stack_register.top();
   ```